# Is this an efficient code for Multi Key Dictionary in a Method Body?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, dictionary

I just want to ask if:

1. The code below is efficient?
2. Is there a better way to handle this?
3. How to code if additional values for tablename/fieldname pair are needed?

We need to use a multi-key dictionary that contains something like (TableName, FieldName, FieldValue).

I searched some answer but the ones I found so far are not applicable to our setup.  We are using 3.5 so no Tuple available yet.  We are also integrating this script logic with an application that only allows coding "inside" a method body, so we are limited and cannot create a separate class/structure, etc.  Our set up is C#/VS 2010.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> tableList = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();
Dictionary<string, string> fieldList = new Dictionary<string, string>();

// add fields to field list, then add the field lists to the corresponding table list
// clear field list for next table
// values are just hardcoded here to simplify, but is being read from actual objects in the application

fieldList.Add("Field1", "abc");
fieldList.Add("Field2", "def");
fieldList.Add("Field3", "ghi");
fieldList.Add("Field4", "jkl");

tableList.Add("Table1", new Dictionary<string, string>(fieldList));
fieldList.Clear();

fieldList.Add("Field1", "xyz");
fieldList.Add("Field2", "uvw");
fieldList.Add("Field3", "rst");

tableList.Add("Table2", new Dictionary<string, string>(fieldList));
fieldList.Clear();

fieldList.Add("Field1", "123");
fieldList.Add("Field2", "456");

tableList.Add("Table3", new Dictionary<string, string>(fieldList));
fieldList.Clear();

// Display tables and corresponding fields                          

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Dictionary<string, string>> fieldList4 in tableList)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> fieldList5 in fieldList4.Value)
    {
        txtMessage.Text = txtMessage.Text + "\r\nTable=" + fieldList4.Key + ", Field=" + fieldList5.Key + " - " + fieldList5.Value;
    }
}

// Try to find tables and fields in the lists, and list the value if found

string tableToFind = "Table2";
string fieldToFind = "Field2";
Dictionary<string, string> tableFields = new Dictionary<string, string>();

if (tableList.Keys.Contains(tableToFind) == true)
{
    txtMessage.Text = txtMessage.Text = "\r\nTable=" + tableToFind + " exist in table list";
    tableList.TryGetValue(tableToFind, out tableFields);

    if (tableFields.Keys.Contains(fieldToFind) == true)
    {
        foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> fieldData  in tableFields)
        {
            if (fieldData.Key == fieldToFind)
            {
                txtMessage.Text = txtMessage.Text + "\r\nTable=" + tableToFind + ", Field=" +  fieldData.Key + 
                                                    " with value=" + fieldData.Value + " exist in table list";
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not take advantage of some of the helpful syntax sugar provides?

Comment: A way to do it with a single dictionary would be to join the table key and field key into one string eg. "Table1|Field1". No idea if this is more efficient though.

Comment: if you have a requirement for weakly typed dataset semantics, is there any reason not to use those classes? i think the best would be to use a strongly typed solution if possible.

Comment: I think this question would be more appropriate for [codereview.se].

Comment: [chaorpandion] sorry, kinda newbie. syntax sugar? 

[richard d] i'll try that as well. thanks. 

[gabriel]  thanks, and I agree but i cannot use classes because of limitations with the application we are using. basically, we are just creating add-on scripts, which only allows a "within a method" only code. there's a workaround, I'm sure, but this is our easiest option because of time constraint. 

[Jeff Mercado] still new to stackoverflow, so I'll keep your suggestion in mind next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a whole slew of problems and inefficiencies in your code.

1. If you're going to create multiple dictionaries, create the dictionaries directly.  Don't use a separate instance to fill the values and copy from.
2. Never use string concatenation in a loop like that.  Use a `StringBuilder` or other similar mechanism to build up your strings.  You already have your values in a collection so using `String.Join()` in conjunction with LINQ would clean that up.
3. Your approach to get values from the dictionary is awkward to say the least.  Normally you'd use `TryGetValue()` alone to attempt to read the key.  Your code uses it incorrectly.  If you are going to check if the key exists in the dictionary (using `Contains()`), then there's no point in using `TryGetValue()`.  To make things worse, you did this *then* searched for the key manually in the inner dictionary by iterating through the key value pairs.

The typical pattern looks like this:

```
DictValueType value;
if (myDict.TryGetValue(key, out value))
{
    // key was in the dictionary, the value is stored in the `value` variable
}
```

The code you have could be written much *much* more efficiently like this:

```
var tableList = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>
{
    { "Table1", new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    { "Field1", "abc" },
                    { "Field2", "def" },
                    { "Field3", "ghi" },
                    { "Field4", "jkl" },
                }
    },
    { "Table2", new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    { "Field1", "xyz" },
                    { "Field2", "uvw" },
                    { "Field3", "rst" },
                }
    },
    { "Table3", new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    { "Field1", "123" },
                    { "Field2", "456" },
                }
    },
};

// Display tables and corresponding fields
txtMessage.Text = String.Join("\r\n",
    tableList.SelectMany(table =>
        table.Value.Select(fieldList =>
            String.Format("Table={0}, Field={1} - {2}",
                table.Key, fieldList.Key, fieldList.Value)
        )
    ).ToArray()
);

// (I hope you have this in a separate method)
// Try to find tables and fields in the lists, and list the value if found
string tableToFind = "Table2";
string fieldToFind = "Field2";

var builder = new StringBuilder(txtMessage.Text); // mostly useful if you have a 
                                                  // lot of different strings to add
Dictionary<string, string> foundTable;
if (tableList.TryGetValue(tableToFind, out foundTable))
{
    builder.AppendLine()
        .Append("Table=" + tableToFind + " exist in table list");

    string foundField;
    if (foundTable.TryGetValue(fieldToFind, out foundField))
    {
        builder.AppendLine()
            .AppendFormat("Table={0}, Field={1} with value={2} exist in table list",
                tableToFind, fieldToFind, foundField);
    }
}
txtMessage.Text = builder.ToString();
```

Nested dictionaries aren't a bad thing, it's a nice way to organize hierarchies of keys and values.  But to keep it maintainable, you generally should encapsulate everything within another class providing methods to manipulate the data without having to manage the dictionaries directly.  You can make it both efficient and maintainable.  How to implement this is an exercise left to you.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the compiler to create a composite key for you: Using anonymous types.

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<Object, int>();

dictionary.Add(new{Text="A", Number=1}, 1);
dictionary.Add(new{Text="A", Number=2}, 3);
dictionary.Add(new{Text="B", Number=1}, 4);
dictionary.Add(new{Text="B", Number=2}, 5);

var x = dictionary[new{Text="B", Number=2}];
```

C# will implement Equals and GetHashcode based on your fields. Thus you do get a key which will behave as you would expect.

Comment: That's interesting. The compiler generates an `Equals` method that compares each field. I didn't know it would do that.

Comment: @robert. this is interesting indeed.  i'll try this as well. thanks!

Comment: OMG! This is like the holy grail in Multi Key Dictionaries. You wouldn't believe the lengths people have gone to create multi key or array based key dictionaries. Thank you!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so many dictionaries would be 'efficient'.

I think the best way would be to add values into the same dictionary multiple times - assuming you want to be able to index them according to one of the indicies (not all):

```
dictionary.Add("FField1", "xxx");
dictionary.Add("TTable1", "xxx");
```

Otherwise use a joining character (like `'\0'`) if you want to index them according to all the indicies together.

```
dictionary.Add("Table1\0Field1", "xxx");
```

Comment: The first method has a couple of problems. If `FField1` exists in multiple tables, then you have the problem of duplicate keys. Also, the maximum size of your dictionary is cut in half because you have twice as many keys. The second option, constructing a composite key, is a good one, though.

Comment: @Jim indeed, although I couldn't make out how he wanted to index - so I had to present both solutions.

Comment: @jonathan, jim.  thanks for your answers.  i'll try if the second option will be a better option with what I wanted to do.

basically, what i want to do is to create a searchable holder to get the selected list of tables, their fields, and selected custom field attributes -- to avoid frequent access to the database.